# Would my timezone affect the rate of change in my reputation and upvotes?

Tags: discussion

Most websites, including Stack Overflow, have a "hot" time when it receives maximum traffic from a certain geography. This would directly affect the interaction my answers and questions would receive when they are fresh and listed in fresh "Top Questions".

So, my hypothesis is, let's assume that biggest percentage of highly active developers (people who write, comment and vote very actively) comes from the USA. Would I be receiving a better rate of interaction with my questions and answers if I post them during USA daytime, instead of my daytime, which is night for the US ?

I understand that Stack Overflow is about mutually helping each other, and such minor reputation affecting factors should not be chased. My question is instead regarding the following two points:

- Does this hypothesis stand true from data analysis?
- Do Stack Overflow's question feed algorithms factor in visitors' timezones to nullify such visibility biases?

Comment: Somewhat related (doesn't cover user activity though): [Where in the world do Stack Overflow users say they are from?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25598/where-in-the-world-do-stack-overflow-users-say-they-are-from)

Comment: Regarding your second question: I doubt there is anything that implicitly tries to overcome the timezone biases.  There is just so much content and so many new questions.

Comment: You can run the analysis yourself using [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/). The data are as much as a week old, but that shouldn't hurt an analysis like this.